# Monitoring Rails+Nginx+Unicorn logs for errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, monitoring, logging

What are some suggested methods for monitoring my production environment logs for errors?

My stack consists of **Rails 3**,  **nginx**, **unicorn** and **bluepill** (which monitors **unicorn**). The ideal solution would notify me immediately if an error shows up in the logs for any of those applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with [Exception Notification](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification). If you start getting too many duplicate error emails, then switch to something like [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home).